# Rails 4 - Facebook clear cache for sharing button / link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, caching, share

I have a "Share on facebook" link on a profile page that have dynamic content such as user avatar and job.

If a user share the content on facebook, facebook open graph take the good infos inside og:meta and do the work properly. If the user change it's infos and clic again the "Share on facebook" link, the infos aren't updated because of open graph caching.
I want the content to be updated, so then to flush the open graph cache on demand (when the user triggers the link or opens the page).

Here is what I have found (and not working):

Test1: using debugger tool

```
config/initializers/facebook_og.rb
    module FacebookOpenGraph
      def self.clear_cache(url)
        uri = URI('https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object')
        res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'q' => "#{url}")
      end
    end
```

Test2: using open graph

```
config/initializers/facebook_og.rb
module FacebookOpenGraph
  def self.clear_cache(url)
    uri = URI('https://graph.facebook.com')
    res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'id' => "#{url}", 'scrape' => 'true')
  end
end
```

Test3: using API (found here: http://mdenomy.wordpress.com/2014/01/)

```
config/initializers/facebook_og.rb    
module FacebookOpenGraph
      def self.clear_cache(url)
        params = {
          :client_id => ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'],
          :client_secret => ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'],
          :grant_type => "client_credentials"
        }
        uri = URI("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?#{params.to_query}")
        response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
        access_token = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(response)["access_token"]
        unless access_token.nil?
          uri = URI('https://graph.facebook.com')
          res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'id' => "#{url}", 'scrape' => 'true',
              'access_token' => "#{access_token}", 'max' => '500')
        end
      end
    end
```

In my page, I add this line on top, before og meta calls:

```
<% FacebookOpenGraph.clear_cache(controller_action_url(@user, subdomain: 'player')) %>
```

I tried to add a random number like `http://player.domain.com/2?<%= rand(1000..9999) %>`, with no success

Basically, none of these techniques work. So... any help would be really appreciated.
(sorry for my bad english)
KR.

Comment: What happens if you try to clear the cache using the Facebook debug tool? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/   Enter in the URL that you are trying to clear the cache for and see if you get any errors or if it is successful.

Comment: Also this might help with problems you run into trying to use the FaceBook debug tool  http://mdenomy.wordpress.com/2014/01/12/facebook-url-linter-critical-errors-and-rackspace/

Comment: If I do it manually, cache is flushed properly.
I tried to automate this in the Test 1, basically 'https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object' is the url generated by facebook when you press the debug button, and it passes the p="your url" via post. I'm wondering if my Problem isn't the url I pass, maybe I have to parse it. I Hope that I understood your question correctly. Thank you

Comment: it's a "q="yoururl" in post, not a "p=", sorry for the typo.

Comment: BTW, when I copy-paste the 'developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?p="myurl" in firefox address bar, it returns the debugger page with warning "Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped."

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made it work with the Test 3 API Version (thank to mdenomy) and I put it in a background job triggered when user update it's infos.

My problem was the url that didn't work properly (subdomain & i18n locale & escaping the whole properly). Everything works fine now.

Comment: you done following this https://mdenomy.wordpress.com/2014/01/20/programmatically-clearing-the-facebook-share-image-cache/#comment-825 ? Works perfect! Thanks